# "MySQL connection failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" How to fix it

Tags: php, mysql

Yes I've seen all related posts on stackoverflow regarding the same problem

I'm using mamp + php + mysql

But the error shows on my web browser when I generate the codes on this website: http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Make sure your db connection string is correct.

Comment: @Rikesh any suggestions of improvements on code?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the MySQL service is running.

Sometimes this causes the issue.

If it was running properly, check if the username and password you've set up to connect to the database are correct.

In the above code these have many occurrences.

Search for the line below throughout the code and set the correct username, password, and table name:

```
    $dbLink = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pwd', 'myTable');
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using the IP?? if so then replace is with localhost.. Actually default user can not access the DB using the localhost IP. 127.0.0.1.  change it to localhost or create new user who can access.

Comment: i will say to give a try atleast.. actually once I faced the problem and it resolved my issue thats why saying otherwise I dont have interest to tell u something awkward.. !!!

Comment: The error message does say that access is denied to `'user'@'localhost'`, so it would seem that he's already using localhost.

Comment: Yes @andrewsi what do you suggest instead?

Comment: I'd probably concentrate on your second point. From the error message, it looks like MySQL is running, but the user credentials are incorrect. I'd suggest the OP doublecheck that the credentials he's using are correct (say, by connecting from the command line); or creating a new user that definitely has the right permissions.